# Pivotal, Imperative, use of hyphens

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

> Since the Social Media is pivotal to building and maintaining interpersonal relationships - hence, central to human existence - it becomes imperative to investigate the current trend in language use on this principal communication media.

I want to know if this sentence is grammatical and unambiguous. Thank you.

Comment: Ok... So what is your question?

Comment: It's grammatical. They hyphens should be dashes, and there's no need for a comma after "hence."  But that's punctuation.  The words between dashes form an aside, a construct linked only loosely to the rest of the sentence.  Because of the excessive abstraction, the sentence doesn't say much, but it's clear that it means that someone needs to study tweets because they're important.  But trust me, "social media" is not central to human existence.

Comment: @Catija The OP's original formatting didn't appear in the question - they're asking about the first sentence.

Comment: Hello, Victory Hils. Unless you can be more specific about the nature of your concern about the quoted sentence, the request will probably be interpreted as a request for proofreading/copyediting help, which this site does not provide. Please try to be specific about what aspect(s) of the sentence are worrisome to you, and why. Thanks!